# Up / Down Arrow jQuery Events on Search box

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to implement similar functionality as mentioned in
[jQuery Key Events with a Search Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583025/jquery-key-events-with-a-search-box)

I would like to arrow up and down the search results and select the result on enter key or mouse click.

Find my code at: http://jsfiddle.net/CyQ2w/

**3 issues:**

I am able to arrow up and down, but when I arrow down after the last item, the selection on item disappears. I am trying to disable browsing after last item i.e., keep the last item selected. Same thing happens for first item when we up arrow on it.

When I mouse over the item list and mouse out, the selection hover is removed and now arrow up and down do not work.

Also, on enter key doesn't seem to set the textarea with the item selected. I am trying to capture "id" of selected li.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your **first** problem you can add a check like the following -

```
...
else if (code === 40) { //Down arrow
        if($("li.hovered").index()==$("li").length-1) return;
...
else if (code === 38) { //Up arrow
        if($("li.hovered").index()==0) return;
        ...
```

This means when you are in the first item `index 0` pressing the up arrow will do nothing.

BTW, 38 is not down arrow its up arrow. Don't make other confused. <s>I hope you can do the Down check yourself.</s>

You can solve the **second** problem like the following -

```
$("#userlist_container li").hover(function () {
    $('li.hovered').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
}, function () {
    // $(this).removeClass("hovered");
});
```

And your **third** problem is little hard to explain without the whole code so check my updated code at http://jsfiddle.net/CyQ2w/7/

You should block events with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: +1 Perfecto! Up arrow issue seems to be solved. Sorry for the wrong comment. Have updated in jfiddle. :)

Comment: I was able to fix the down arrow issue. Thanks to your index logic.

Comment: It works. I needed id of selected li, so I used ("li.hovered").attr("id"). Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: When I do up / down arrow in the list, the cursor in textarea also moves up / down. How can I prevent this in textarea? .blur() will remove focus and at the same time I won't be able to use arrow keys in list.

Comment: Put `e.preventDefault()` in up, down also